# What does "Copy projects into workspace" mean?

Tags: eclipse

When importing a project into Eclipse, there is a checkbox "Copy projects into workspace". I want to know what does this mean. Do I need to select this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Every project in Eclipse is part of a workspace, which can be any folder, but usually developers keep the workspace folder as a parent to project folders. So, in this context, Eclipse is asking you, if you already have a workspace, whether you want to copy the project you are importing, to that workspace.

I will explain with an example: for my Android work, I have workspace folder called `Android-<Product-Name>`. In this I have library projects `lib1`, `lib2`, and the base Android project (called `<product-name>`) that uses those libraries. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Is it best practice to put the projects, and their source trees, underneath the workspace folder?

Comment: Generally speaking, yes it is. But in some exceptions it wont be applicable. There will always be cases when the "best practices" don't apply. Use your judgement.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Since I'm managing my project changes with Git SCM, I figure it's best not to have more than one copy of a checked out repository on the system.

Answer (score 20):

Basically, you want to do this if you want to copy the files of the project you are importing under the workspace folder, and have two copies of the project on your computer at once. This may or may not be what you want to do. In my case it is not what I want to do, as I already have my projects placed in the proper and final location before I import them. My "workspace" folder remains void of project files. This is completely acceptable and is likely what a newcomer to Eclipse working on a test project will want to do. If you are working for someone else, you should ask your employer the setup protocol.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this. I have a folder in a different location than the workspace where I already checked out my project from SVN, and I certainly wouldn't want two copies on my hard drive.